# Why is the following code giving runtime error SIGSEGV

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

I am writing the solution to a programming problem. The problem is as follows:

> Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the
>   Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely...
>   rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input
>   after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of
>   one or two digits.

I have pasted my code below. I am getting segmentation fault when I submit this solution. Can someone point out what's wrong with this code? Any help will be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int number = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c != EOF)
        {
            number = number * 10 + c;
        }
        else
        {
            //const char value = number;
            if (number != 42)
            {
                printf(number);
                printf("\n");
                number = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.3

Comment: If you would have raised the warning levels of your compiler to a maximum, he would have told you.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
printf(number);
```

is invalid. You're missing the required format specifier with `printf()`. You want to write

```
printf("%d", number);
```

Also, `printf()` being a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), it can accept one or more arguments and as long as that criteria is met, compilation will not fail. However, this instance, will cause [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of mismatched argument type.

Comment: And why is it compiling? I think it would be good to explain.